# change the postgres query to laravel query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I have the postgres query which I want to convert it into laravel query

Postgres query

```
select string_agg(col, ', ' order by col) 
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(geo_access) - 'id') t(col, val)
        where t.val = '1') as geos from geo_access
```

I have tries in laravel as

```
DB::table ('geo_access')->raw("select string_agg(col, ', ' order by col) 
        from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(geo_access) - 'id') t(col, val)
        where t.val = '1' as geos" )->get();
```

I have caught the error as
**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::where()**

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `select()` instead

```
$result = \DB::select("select string_agg(col, ', ' order by col) from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(geo_access) - 'id') t(col, val) where t.val = '1') as geos from geo_access");
```

Comment: getting error as  Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...(geo_access) - 'id') t(col, val) where t.val = '1') as geos ...
^ (SQL: select string_agg(col, ', ' order by col) from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(geo_access) - 'id') t(col, val) where t.val = '1') as geos from geo_access

Comment: That is query error, you might want to check back your query.

Comment: my postgres query is working fine .but not in laravel